# How to Include Space in VBA Text file output

Tags: vba, excel

How can I include space as part of my output in VBA?

I currently have this code below:

```
CellData = "AAAAA" & Space & "BBBBB"
```

And I want to generate output like this below:

```
"AAAAA" "BBBBB"
```

But using the code above, I was only able to generate:

```
"AAAAA""BBBBB"
```

Comment: it'd be nice from you to give feedback to people trying at helping you. So please take your time and close this question as well as all of your other still open questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Well `" "` is a space so

```
?"AAAAA" & " " & "BBBBB"
AAAAA BBBBB
```

Or if you want the quotes

```
?"""AAAAA""" & " " & """BBBBB""
"AAAAA" "BBBBB"
```

Which is of course:

```
? """AAAAA"" ""BBBBB""
"AAAAA" "BBBBB"
```

`Space` if a function name so what you have is not valid, you could:

```
"AAAAA" & Space$(1) & "BBBBB"
```

For a single space.

Answer (score 2):

Either of these will work:

```
Sub PrintSpace()
    Debug.Print "a" & Chr(32) & "a"
    Debug.Print "a" & " " & "a"
End Sub
```